# Jerky playback from avplayer on Applying Rate greater than 2x

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avplayer, playback

I want to tweak Avplayer rate , I able to do with help of

```
[_avplayer play];
[_avplayer setRate:1.5];
```

Also disabled audio tracks , it is running good when it is less than 2.0.
But when we apply it greater than 2X it results in Choppy or jerky video.

When i googled about this - I found this one link suggesting same behaviour

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1772/_index.html

> Playing at rates greater than 2.0 can result in jerky or choppy playback when the data rate or other processing requirements of
>   playing at the specified rate exceeds the ability of AVFoundation to
>   keep up. In those cases, AVPlayer automatically degrades the quality
>   of playback in order to keep up, employing a tier of fallback
>   strategies depending on prevailing conditions. One tier of degradation
>   is to decode and display only I-frames within the video substream, and
>   this can indeed appear to be choppy.

Can any one  help like if it so , than what approach shall i use to achieve same ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @Rhythmic suggested these ways can be implemented but these all are kind of hassle . I googled it more and found a way and it is working very fine no jerk or choppy .

Just do not set rate , set Rate like this . First create instance of AVPlayer , AVPlayerItem  and AVAsset  .

```
  AVMutableComposition *composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
        NSError *error = nil;
        [composition insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration)
                             ofAsset:asset
                              atTime:kCMTimeZero error:&error];
        [composition scaleTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration)
                         toDuration:CMTimeMultiplyByFloat64(asset.duration, 1 / rate)];
        AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:composition];
        self.avRefPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

        self.avRefPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer layer];

        [self.avRefPlayerLayer setPlayer:self.avRefPlayer];
        [self.avRefPlayerLayer setFrame:_refrencedView.bounds];
        [self.avRefPlayerLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
```

this code can even support more than 2x or 4x speed easily .

Comment: FWIW, two applications that I created—one in Objective-C and the other in Swift—both exhibit this problem.  It's worth noting that the issue is not the media file: Quicktime Player, for example, has no trouble playing it back very fast, whereas my applications cannot seem to do more than about 1.5x.  I've just implemented the above in Swift and found that it does work.  I can play back at, for example, 9x, no problem.

Comment: This works great. However event by adjusting time scale changes and doing the proper seeks, changing the speed while playing the video is still very hard get right without weird frame jumps. Since the framework is obviously capable of playing at fast rates, I still don't understand while the `rate` property doesn't support it...

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Kshitij Godara.

Converted to **Swift 4**.

```
let timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTime(seconds: videoDuration, preferredTimescale: 1))
let composition = AVMutableComposition()
try composition.insertTimeRange(timeRange,
                               of: asset,
                               at: kCMTimeZero)
composition.scaleTimeRange(timeRange, toDuration: CMTimeMultiplyByFloat64(asset.duration, Float64(1.0 / rate)))
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: composition)
let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
player.play()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try a few things:

1. lower the framerate of your video
2. add more I-frames to your video (this may be slightly perverse, considering [QA-1772's advice](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1772/_index.html))
3. decode (or better? encode) the video at a lower resolution
4. lower the bitrate of the video
5. measure how much faster than realtime `AVAssetReader` can decode at  & replace `AVPlayer` with your own `Metal` + `AVAssetReader` path if you think that some performance has gotten lost in transit. Don't forget to consider audio, too, if you take this path.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in AVFoundation.  It *can* play smoothly at fast rates for many videos where, under most circumstances, it doesn't.  For example, one can use AVPlayerView's floating controller style to expose a fast-forward button.  Clicking this button repeatedly results in smooth, fast playback where simply setting `AVPlayer.rate` does not.

In my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30346405/how-do-you-get-smooth-high-rate-playback-from-avplayer/42297076#42297076) I explain a workaround for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch 0~4 rate, you can initialize an AVMutableComposition that has been scale duration to 1/2, and then set the rate to 0~2 during playback.