# AVPlayer takes long time to start playing

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

After the update to Swift 3 I´ve realised that my App takes long time to start playing an audio file from a remote server. In Swift 2.3 this didn't´t happen. I´ve been trying to debug it all day long but I couldn't´t find anything. I´ve been printing the states of the AVPlayer at each moment and I found that it changes from `Loading` to `Playing` within seconds but then it takes around 20 seconds to really start playing the song.

I am using Jukebox by TeodorPatras

Comment: Does this happen when debugging only or also, if you disconnect the device from your computer and start the app on the device?

Comment: @shallowThought Also when I start the app on the device

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally fixed it myself with the next line of code:

```
player?.playImmediately(atRate: 1.0)
```

What that line does is, it starts playing immediately without ensuring that the buffer it´s enough to not suffer interruptions. But in my case I prefer that over having to wait for several seconds.

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem but its not worked for me. Do i have to replace player.play() with your code or i have to keep both?

Comment: @MaheshNarla Replace.

Comment: The only supported values are 0.50, 0.67, 0.80, 1.0, 1.25, 1.50, and 2.0. All other settings are rounded to nearest value.

Comment: @Maneeios How do you know that it's the only supported values? I searched and didn't find

Comment: @RoiMulia I go this info from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630356/avplayer-rate-property-does-not-work

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issues with the devices with iOS 10 only. The solution to support iOS 10 and the old iOS versions is this:

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    player?.playImmediately(atRate: 1.0)
} else {
    player?.play()
}
```